# invokeElementMethod in Renderer2 angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-renderer2, angular-renderer

**Context** Angular project 
I have the following snippet:

```
export class OnlyNumberDirective {
  constructor(private _el: ElementRef,private renderer:Renderer2) {
  }
  @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInputChange(e) {
    this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this._el.nativeElement, 'dispatchEvent', [event]);
  }
}
```

it uses Renderer, but it is deprecated and now we have Renderer2? 
What is the alternative to `invokeElementMethod` method in `Renderer2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one:

```
export class OnlyNumberDirective {
  constructor(private _el: ElementRef) {
  }
  @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInputChange(e) {
    let event: Event = document.createEvent("Event");
    event.initEvent('input', true, true);
    Object.defineProperty(event, 'target', { value: this._el.nativeElement, enumerable: true });
    this._el.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [migration guide](https://angular.io/guide/migration-renderer), it appears the following replacement should work

```js
(this._el.nativeElement as any)['dispatchEvent'].apply(this._el.nativeElement, [event]);
```